# Meta tag getting added after style tag in head

Tags: angular

I am adding meta tag dynamically,
I am able to add those using importing meta and using update meta tag methos.

But those tags are getting added after style tag in html header in angular,

Is there any way, i can add those just after opening of head tag in angular

Answer (score 1):

Angular does provide a way to update meta tag dynamically.

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta

Take a look at this tutorial. https://dev.to/angular/how-i-dynamically-updated-the-title-and-meta-tags-in-my-angular-application-4kdp

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular Lovers';

constructor(
    private title: Title,
    private meta: Meta
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.title.setTitle('Dynamic Hello Angular Lovers Title');
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'Dynamic Hello Angular Lovers description!' });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply: Add `meta` after `header` with empty content `name`. After that, update the content with using `meta.updateTag`, then the content will update dynamically.